# Part of 3D annulus (cylinder)

Tags: geometry, 3d

Is there a special name of an object that is basically a 3D annulus? I mean a case of a simple 2D annulus that is "elevated" straight from the ground up. A short tube/pipe could be an example of such object. In German it seems to be called "Hohlzylinder".

Here is what I mean:

[image]

A bonus question: I actually need to name only a part of this object that is defined by a central angle (like 90 degrees). How to name that? I am writing a thesis and don't know how to name this object.

Comment: I would call it a tube. I don't think there is a common mathematical name for such an object in English. I like the German name, very descriptive.

Comment: Hollow cylinder?