# What do you call a 3D annulus/cylindrical shell and parts of it?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Take a cylinder and punch a centered circular hole through it--like a washer. What is that shape called? In 2D it's an annulus, but what's the name of its 3D equivalent?[image: cylindrical shell]

Also, what is this shape called when you remove part of it along 2 radii?[image]

Comment: The first half is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745408/part-of-3d-annulus-cylinder .

Comment: 1) coaxial cylinder / annular cylinder 2) coaxial cylindrical sector?

Answer (score 1):

[Coaxial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coaxial) or [annular](http://www.mathcaptain.com/geometry/annulus.html) cylinder.

In a sphere it's a [spherical ring](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalRing.html). If the remainder of the cutout is round it's a donut or [toroid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroid) but Wikipedia shows a square toroid too. English.SE has a [dozen answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/230562/246019), depending on usage.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing hard and fast, depends on local industry usage or custom.

Some suggestions

**First image**

*Thick cylinder*

*Thick hollow cylinder*

*Flat Ring Blank*

**Second image**

*Prismatic punched sector*

*Thick Prismatic annular sector*

*Thick punched sector*